# Quantity available column should automatically reduce when the sales table quantity increases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stock (Date, Description, Product_Code, DEO, Cartons, Items, Quantity, Sent_To) VALUES ('$date','$description', '$productcode','$deo', '$cartons', '$items', '$quantity', '$sent_to')";
    //$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM stockcount WHERE Product_Code = '".$productCode."';
    //$sql1 = mysqli_query("UPDATE stockcount SET Quantity='" . Quantity-$quantity . "' WHERE Product_Code='$productcode'");


    if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE) {

        header("Location:sendorder.php");

    }
    else {

        echo "Error is " .$sql."<br>". $conn->error;
    }
```

$sql inserts date, description, product_code, deo, cartons, items, quantity and sent to stocks table.
product_code is a foreign key in the stock table and its inserted through a dropdown. I want to locate to the product in stockcout table through the product code and reduce its quantity by the quantity that was inserted through $sql. Please help me to generate a query that could update the quantity through the product_code in stock count table.I have tried some queries that i commented please check those too. [You can see both the stock and stockcount table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rndek.png). I would be really glad if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  It makes a difference to the answer.  Please remove the incorrect tag.

Answer (score 0):

A mysql trigger should be used. Up on successful row insertion, the trigger should be activated and you should have logic to do whatever you want to do.

Trigger ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html